# Aframe - 0.7.0 gives a "t.substr is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, aframe

http://agilelens.altervista.org/aframe/index.html

Looks like t.substr maybe was a function in previous versions of aframe but not anymore?

Here's the error:

```
aframe.min.js:115 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.substr is not a function
at Gi.load (aframe.min.js:115)
at Vi.load (aframe.min.js:115)
at init (aframe-overunder-viewer.js:75)
at i.updateProperties (aframe.min.js:296)
at i.module.exports.Component (aframe.min.js:296)
at new i (aframe.min.js:296)
at HTMLElement.value (aframe.min.js:288)
at HTMLElement.value (aframe.min.js:288)
at HTMLElement.Object.create.updateComponents.value (aframe.min.js:288)
at aframe.min.js:288
```

Comment: The demo seems to be working, and I can't see an error in the console. Note that the stack trace is coming through aframe-overunder-viewer.js, so something inside that file is not compatible with 0.7.0, to narrow things down.

Comment: Weirdly, the demo works the first time on a new device, but then throws the error on subsequent visits. Maybe a cache problem?